# gwt onMouseOver and onMouseOut on Firefox

Tags: firefox, gwt

I have an image. I plan to put a transparent popup with little icons on top of it when the mouse is over the image, and the popup is hidden when the mouse is outside of the image. It is just similar to youtube. For Microsoft Edge and Chrome, the onMouseOver and onMouseOut are just triggered and handled as expected. For Firefox, I find the definition of onMouseOver/onMouseOut are a bit different. I need to switch to another application by Alt Tab and come back to the browser to trigger the onMouseOver. Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

```
evtPic.addMouseOverHandler(new MouseOverHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onMouseOver(MouseOverEvent event) {
            
            popupScreen.setPopupPosition(evtPic.getAbsoluteLeft(), evtPic.getAbsoluteTop());
            if(!popupScreen.isShowing())
            {
                popupScreen.show();
            }
        }
    });
    
    evtPic.addMouseOutHandler(new MouseOutHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onMouseOut(MouseOutEvent event) {
            if(popupScreen.isShowing())
            {
                popupScreen.hide();
            }
        }
    });
```

Thanks

Comment: Isn't it because after showing a popup, mouse is not longer over the pic but over the popup? Try to show the popoup relative to mouse position not the pic position and move it a little so it will not be shown under the cursor.

Comment: I move the popup position to somewhere not close to the leftmost corner. The onMouseOver and onMouseOut are triggered as expected. Thanks